# Can I use Dexron III H for power transmission requiring Dexron IID/III?

Tags: oil, automatic-transmission, power-steering

I've got a [Freelander 1999 2.0L DI](http://www.auto-data.net/en/?f=showCar&car_id=5181). I need to top up some power steering fluid. In the manual it says to use Dexron IID or Dexron III. I'm wondering whether I can use Dexron III **H** (e.g. [Castrol ATF DEX III](http://www.castrol.com/en_au/australia/products/cars/automatic-transmission-fluids/atf-dex-iii.html)) for this purpose as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be fine using the Dexron-IIIH. The "H" indicates a newer additive package than previous versions. According to [OilSpecifications.org](http://www.oilspecifications.org/general_motors_gm.php):

> Dexron III licence H was introduced in June 2003 to replace the Dexron III G fluid. It has an oxidatively stable base oil (group 2 or group 3). Oils according to this specification have longer maintenance of friction properties and anti-shrudder properties, better foam control and a longer fluid life.

It's just *better* Dexron-III, is all.